# Strptime presumes hours inconsistently

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, strptime

I have a (pandas) Series of numbers like

```
20170809
20181231
```

I want to convert them into datetime objects. this is trivial with an apply wrapped around `datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%M%d')`. However, datetime is adding on hours that are different. For instance:

```
 20011231 2001-01-31 00:12:00
 20050102 2005-01-02 00:01:00
 20000815 2000-01-15 00:08:00
```

How can I force strptime to assume the same hour/minute/second for every string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month is `m`. The capital `M` means minute.

You do:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('20011231', '%Y%M%d')
datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 31, 0, 12)
```

but need to do:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('20011231', '%Y%m%d')
datetime.datetime(2001, 12, 31, 0, 0)
```

Comment: oh my gosh, so stupid. i didn't even bother to check the sample output I pasted in SO! thanks much